# Can't filter date and time record using postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to filter a record by date-time, but no success.
When I send the request from the client to the server, I can see that the date and time matches with the value stored in the entity. However, there's something I'm not understanding on the record, and I think it is the problem from not succeeding the filter.

I'd like to know how to store only date and time in postgres.

[image: records from entity]

You can see in the image that it is not just storing the date and time, it has more information, and I would like to know how to save the date and time only, without this numerical sequence that comes after the time.

For example, I don't want it to be saved as: `2022-03-28 09:50:26.077`
I want it to be saved like this: `2022-03-28 09:50:26`

I've done a lot of research and haven't found any resources that can help me with this issue. I really don't know why it's saving this number sequence, I don't know if this is something that involves timezone...

**Script SQL**

```
create table mytable (
  ...
  column_name timestamp not null default now()::timestamp
);
```

How to proceed with this? Is there any technique to remove those numbers and leave only the date and time?

Comment: If you don't want fractional seconds you can define the column as `timestamp(0)` - but that only means it will be stored e.g. as `2022-03-28 09:50:26.000`. But in the end it's a essentially something you need to solve when you _display_ those values in your application.

Comment: You are storing the  just the date and time, where the time portion has seconds to millisecond precision. You can use `timestamp(0)` per previous comment but that may result in rounding so again it may not match whatever you are comparing against.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_TRUNC():

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id int,
  column_name timestamp not null default date_trunc('second', now()::timestamp)
);

INSERT INTO mytable(id) VALUES(1) RETURNING *;
```